# javascript:variable value passing from javascript to php

Tags: php, javascript

I have a `javascript` file `pet.js`. I want to pass a value of variable in `test.php`. But i can't.

my `pet.js` is like

```
$('#pmWorkOrderDetailsPage').live('pageshow', function(event) {
var id = getUrlVars()["id"];
$.get("test.php", { test1: id } );
$.getJSON('pmworkorderdetails.php?id='+id, displaypmWODetails);
});

function displaypmWODetails(data) {
 ..............code..........
 }
```

My `test.php` is like

```
<?php
$ms = $_GET["test1"];
echo $ms;
?>
```

But it is not working. I tried with `Ajax` and `post` method.

It will be best if I can store the variable value on the session in test.php.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You have an `echo` statement in test.php, but you're not using a callback to handle that data in pet.js. What exactly do you want to do with the output of test.php?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Do you get any errors in your console? Is 'id' filled correctly before you do the ajax call (log it in your console)?

Comment: try `echo json_encode($ms);`. Also, you may need to add a json header

Comment: Try some more using xmlhttprequest. So many people have made it. Search for "xhr javascript example".

Comment: Where's your callback for the first get request?  You're making the request and passing in a parameter, but there is no function being called once it returns with something.  Also bear in mind that it will be asynchronous, so if getjson relies on the data that comes back from it, you'll need to do that in the callback.

Comment: @Andrew i like to receive value in `test.php` for future use.@FAngel How can i do that?

Comment: @Dawn i like to receive value in `test.php`

Answer (score 0):

1 do not use  `getUrlVars()` it can make site vulnerable to xss

```
$('#pmWorkOrderDetailsPage').live('click', function(event) {
var id;// get id
$.get("test.php?id="+id,function(data){

var result=$.parseJSON(data);
 alert(result["content"])
 });

 })
```

test.php

```
<?php

 $id=$_GET['id'];
 $data=array();
  $data=array("content"=>$id);
 echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: so would you plz tell me whats the error..? try to alert(new);

Comment: It is working 50%(lol).alert is showing with accurate id value.but in `test.php` showing `{"content":null}`.If it is possible to get in `test.php`!!

Comment: how it could be possible that alert shows the right id and you don't have id in test.php ?